# In-App-Purchases with App Store Hosted Content. How Subscription works

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

With App Store Hosted Content I can download my purchases (magazine issues in this case) with method *[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:array* where array are *SKDownload* objects that I retrive from *SKPaymentTransaction* object to which I have access after user make purchase or after  I restore previously completed purchases.
Now in my app I have auto-renewable subscription, normally if I would have content on my backend server I would just check if user purchased subscription and then let him download content. How should I implement it in scenerio where content is hosted on Apple Store, and only way (that I know) to download it is to use method I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found in this guidline

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios_6/changes_to_storekit/

that In-App Purchase Hosted Content doesn't support subscriptions and not consumable products. Not cool if you ask me :)